# Mathematic notation $a:I\to \Bbb R^3$

Tags: functions

I need a little bit of help with the notation for parametric curve $a$ given below:
$$a:I\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3.$$

What does this notation means?

Best regards,
Sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a:I\to\Bbb R^3$ means that $a$ is a function with domain $I$ and codomain $\Bbb R^3$. Usually, if we're speaking about curves, $I$ is an interval (perhaps $I=[0,1]$) and $a$ is continuous (perhaps $C^1$).

Comment: Thank you, very much.
Another question, if I may, please: say I have a function f(x)=x^2. How do I show that this function or any other function is continuous? Are there some property that can answer this?

Comment: @SergeyDukman If you have not clear what a continuous function is and you want to study curves, you should really have a look at an introductory textbook in real analysis and multivariate calculus for (at least) grasping the case of continuity and/or differentiability in the real variable. Any textbook covering these topics should do.

Answer (score 1):

$a: I \to \mathbb R^3$ means that $a$ is a function with domain $I$ and codomain $ \mathbb R^3.$